# What programming language should you consider to learn if you want to create music apps and music development

Tags: audio

What programming language for sound programming

Comment: You asked this but then only tagged it with javascript tag. add tags for other languages and provide a bit more information. What platform do you want it to run on? mobile, desktop, cross platform?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well there isn't really one magical language to use for making music applications. Assuming you are talking about the back-end, that could vary. For example Spotify's back-end is mostly composed of Python, but there is some Java and C++ on a few servers. iTunes is mainly written in C++, while google music's core is Python.